# Sum values of JavaRDD (Tuple3<String, String, Double>)

Tags: apache-spark, reduce, rdd

I do have a JavaRDD which contains values of a Cassandra Table

```
URL | Name | Value
A   |   x  |    1
A   |   x  |    2   
A   |   x  |    1.5
B   |   y  |    3
B   |   y  |    2.75
C   |   z  |    1.25
C   |   z  |    3 
C   |   z  |    1
```

So I want to reduce this by just having one A, B, C and sum up the values.
I tried it like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple3<String, String, Double>,Double> x = y.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Double>(){

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Double> call(
                Tuple3<String, String, Double> arg0) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }); // To Do reduce
```

y is of type JavaRDD>
but it says that it is not applicable for the argument.
Is it even possible to solve it this way or is there a better one?

Comment: In other words you want to groupByKey and sum by value, right?

Comment: exactly, I thought it will work by using reduceByKey

Comment: and did you try that?

Comment: the problem is, that there is an error in the lines of code I posted above. 
It says:
The method mapToPair(PairFunction<Tuple2<Tuple3<String,String,String>,Double>,K2,V2>) in the type AbstractJavaRDDLike<Tuple2<Tuple3<String,String,String>,Double>,JavaPairRDD<Tuple3<String,String,String>,Double>> is not applicable for the arguments (new PairFunction<Tuple3<String,String,Double>,Tuple3<String,String,Double>,Double>(){})

but to be honest, I have no idea what to do with this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reduceBykey function of JavaRdd, it will reduce data based on the key and create one final Rdd.

Try this code

```
JavaRDD<Tuple3<String, String, Double>> x = ...........;
        JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, Double> result = x.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<Tuple3<String, String, Double>, Tuple2<String, String>, Double>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Double> call(
                            Tuple3<String, String, Double> t)
                            throws Exception {
                        return new Tuple2<Tuple2<String, String>, Double>(
                                new Tuple2<String, String>(t._1(), t
                                        ._2()), t._3());
                    }
                }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Double, Double, Double>() {
            @Override
            public Double call(Double v1, Double v2) throws Exception {
                return v1 + v2;
            }
        });
```